# Fluid not following "Follow Path" object constraint

Tags: fluid-simulation, parent

I have a sphere following a circle around by simply making the circle curve it's "Follow Path" parent. This makes the sphere go around the circle in 100 frames. But when I apply a simple fluid inflow effect to the sphere, the fluid is just being emitted from it's starting position and not following the sphere in a circle. **Why is this happening?**
[image]
[image]

Comment: For me it works, did you try to bake the simulation again? can you upload the blend file?

Comment: provide your blend file

Comment: I uploaded the .blend file